# modify a text javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I set an ID for a text which I want to modify later in javascript.

```
Example:
<hr>
<b>Text:</b>
This is my text to modify.

<hr>
<b>Next Text:</b>
AAA
....
```

I want to modify the text "This is my text to modify." in javascript. I need something like the code below, but how can I set an id for the text I need to modify?

```
document.getElementById('?').innerHTML="modified text";
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
<span id="modify">This is the text to modify</span>
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('modify').innerHTML="New text ";
```

**NOTE:** Instead of `<span>`, you could also use `<p>`, `<h1>` - `<h6>` or any other element.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap text in html tag ie:

```
 <span id="textToModify">Some text</span>
```

and after that you can

```
document.getElementById('textToModify').innerHTML="modified text";
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the "This is my text to modify." into a element and modify that

```
 <p id="text-to-modify">This is my text to modify</p>
 document.getElementById('text-to-modify').innerHTML="modified text";
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, Do something like this

```
Example:
<hr>
<b>Text:</b>
<span id="id1">This is my text to modify.</span>

<hr>
<b>Next Text:</b>
AAA
....
```

And JS like this

```
document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML="modified text";
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
Example:
<hr>
<b>Text:</b>
<a id="myTxt">This is my text to modify.</a>

<hr>
<b>Next Text:</b>
AAA
....
```

And the JS:

```
document.getElementById("myTxt").innerHTML = "Modified!";
```

Comment: Why did you use an `a` tag?

Comment: That is what I usually do.

Comment: <a> is meant for links.. you could have added either <p> or <span>